# iOS Static Libraries Referencing Static Libraries

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible for a static library to link to another static library? For example I would like to have the following workspace structure:

Application
   Static Library 1 
      Static Library Shared
   Static Library 2
      Static Library Shared

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries don't link each other. You need a final executable (in this case the app) or something for all the symbols in the static libraries to resolve. You can have `liba.a` reference symbols that are going to be in `libb.a`, but you'll probably need both `liba.a` and `libb.a` to link the app.  What ultimately ends up being needed depends on the app.

Comment: This is how I set it up and it works great. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the other library's headers on the search path (so your can compile), and then publish the requirement that users of your library will require also the other library.

Also consider using a library manager like [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) to manage this.